# Codeigniter transacciones con multiples funciones

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, transacciones

Necesito agregar un producto en la tabla "productos", una vez agregado el producto retornar el ID de producto, luego necesito agregar los detalles de ese producto en la tabla "detalles_producto"

En la página oficial de Codeigniter muestran cómo hacerlo pero sin utilizar funciones, por ejemplo:

```
$this->db->trans_start(TRUE); // Query will be rolled back
$this->db->query('AN SQL QUERY...');
$this->db->trans_complete();
```

Yo necesito utilizar funciones y mantener la integridad que si una de las dos consultas falla entonces los registros no se agregan, he preparado el siguiente código y quiero saber si de esta manera Codeigniter será capaz de detectar si la consulta falla o No para deshacer los registros O si hay otra mejor práctica u otra forma de hacerlo.

> En vez de usar esto $this->db->query('AN SQL QUERY...'); Estoy usando una función:

```
public function init_product()
{
    $this->db->trans_begin();
    $this->new_product();
    $this->new_product_details();

    if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE)
        $this->db->trans_rollback();
    } else {
        $this->db->trans_commit();
    }
}
```

> Agregando el producto y retornamos el ID del producto agregado

```
public function new_product()
{      
    $data = array(            
        'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
        'details' => $this->input->post('details'),
        'price' => $this->input->post('price')
    );
    $this->db->insert('products', $data);
    if($this->db->affected_rows()) {            
        return $this->db->insert_id();
    }
    return false;
}
```

> Agregando detalles del producto

```
public function new_product_details()
{      
    $data = array(            
        'product_id' => $this->new_product(),
        'user_id' => $this->session->id_user
    );
    $this->db->insert('products', $data);
    if($this->db->affected_rows()) {            
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Como lo especifique anteriormentenecesito saber si esta manera es funcional aunque no siga el ejemplo de la web oficial de Codeigniter, si uso estas funciones Codeigniter puede detectar si las consultas o inserciones en la base de datos fallan, también si pueden darme un mejor ejemplo.

*Agradezco mucho su ayuda por favor*

Comment: El ejemplo que colocaste está muy bien, solamente que estás mandando dos veces llamar new_product.... lo haces desde el init_product y desde new_product_details, fuera de eso las transacciones mandando llamar a funciones con queries está muy bien implementado. Saludos!!!

Comment: Me que da la duda, si por ejemplo esta aplicación es multisession el método `$this->db->insert_id()` no podría caer en un cruce de datos?

Answer (score 1):

Es totalmente funcional lo que escribiste, excepto por un detalle, no se puede obtener el `id` del *producto* en una transacción dentro de Codeigniter, pero desde MySql si es posible.

### Usando [`SELECT last_insert_id()`](https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,115807,115807)

Desde PHP ejecuto lo siguiente y obtengo el `$this->db->insert_id()` de la siguiente manera:

```
public function new_product()
{      
    $data = array(            
        'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
        'details' => $this->input->post('details'),
        'price' => $this->input->post('price')
    );
    $this->db->insert('products', $data);
}

public function new_product_details()
{      
    $data = array(
        'product_id' => 'SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()',
        'user_id' => $this->session->id_user
    );
    // el false es para que no escape como un string la query
    $this->db->insert('products', $data, false);
    if($this->db->affected_rows()) {            
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu planteamiento esta bien.

lo único que tienes que hacer es modificar tu funcion new_product_details para que reciba un parámetro $id_producto  y ya no llamar new product()

```
<?php
public function new_product_details($id_producto)
{      
    $data = array(            
        'product_id' => $id_producto), /*MODIFICAR ESTA LINEA*/
        'user_id' => $this->session->id_user
    );
    $this->db->insert('products', $data);
    if($this->db->affected_rows()) {            
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

y ya en tu función de registro principal utilizas

```
<?php
$new_id_producto = new_product();
new_product_details($new_id_producto);
```